# How to start new level when widget on tkinter overlaps another widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, nokia

so there are a lot of problems going on with this. I attempted to make a snake game in python but It was just a mess so now I'm trying to make it where the only direction they can go after the initial right movement is down and they have to get to the coordinates of the food otherwise it starts over. if they 'eat' the food/square then it will make another level with ought starting new game so I can keep score, however the grow definition doesn't seem to be working at all no matter what I put under the if's. Im using python tkinter.

```
import Tkinter
import random
import math
from Tkinter import *
import time
# Create root window 
####
root = Tkinter.Tk()

#####
# Create Model
######
speed_intvar = Tkinter.IntVar()
speed_intvar.set(1) # Initialize y coordinate
# radius and x-coordinate of circle
new_dir = 0
leng = 40
var = 1
x1 = 10
y1 = 10
x2 = 50
y2 = 10
x3 = x2
y3 = 10
direction = 3
foodx1 = 1
foodx2 = 8
foody1 = 1
foody2 = 8
food_present = 0
length = 8
food = 0# radians of angle in standard position, ccw from positive x axis

######
# Create Controller
#######
# Instantiate and place slider
# Create and place directions for the user
#canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, width=900, height=900, background='#FFFFFF')
#canvas.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=2)
#text = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Use WASD to move', command = new_game)
#text.grid(row=0, column =2)
#text = Tkinter.Label(root, text='Use WASD to move')
#text.grid(row=0, column =2)

######
# Create View
#######
# Create and place a canvas


def new_game():
    c.delete("all")
    canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, width=900, height=900, background='#FFFFFF')
    canvas.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=1)

# Create a circle on the canvas to match the initial model
    circle_item = canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, x2, y3, fill='black', width = "8")
#circle_item2 = canvas.create_rectangle(8, 1, 9, 8, 
#                                outline='#000000', fill='black')


#def move(event):
#    if event.char=='w'






    def food():
        global foodx1, foodx2, foody1, foody2, food_present, food, var
        food_present = 0
        if food_present==0:
            foodx1 = random.randint(1, 900) 
            foody1 = random.randint(1,900)
            foodx2 = foodx1 + 8
            foody2 = foody1 + 8
            food = canvas.create_rectangle(foodx1, foody1, foodx2, foody2, fill = 'black')
            food_present += 1

    food()

#def make_longer():
#    global food_present, food_list, x1, y1, x2, y2, circle_item
#    #x1 = canvas.coords(circle_item)
#    #y1 = canvas.coords(circle_item)
#    #x2 = canvas.coords(circle_item)
#    #y2 = canvas.coords(circle_item)
#    xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2 = canvas.coords(circle_item)
#    xx1 -= 10
#    xx2 -= 50
#    for i in range(len(food_list)):
#        circle_item2=canvas.create_rectangle(xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2, fill ="black")
#make_longer()                   

    def animate():
        global x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, var
        x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = canvas.coords(circle_item)
        #for i in range(food_present):
        if var == 1:
            x1 += 1
            x2 += 1
            #x3+= 1
        if var == 4:
            y1+=1
            y2+=1
            y3+=1
        if var == 5:
            x1-=1
            x2-=1
            x3-=1
        if var == 6:
            y1 -= 1
            y2 -= 1
            y3 -= 1
        canvas.coords(circle_item, x1, y1, x2, y2, x2, y3)
        #canvas.itemconfig(circle_item, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, fill="blue")
        canvas.update()

    #        
    #while 
    # Get the slider data and create x- and y-components of velocity
    #velocity_x = speed_intvar.get() * math.cos(direction) # adj = hyp*cos()
    #velocity_y = speed_intvar.get() * math.sin(direction) # opp = hyp*sin()
    ## Change the canvas item's coordinates
    #canvas.move(circle_item, velocity_x, velocity_y)
    #canvas.move(circle_item2, velocity_x, velocity_y)
    # Get the new coordinates and act accordingly if ball is at an edge



    #global location
    ## If crossing left or right of canvas
    #if x2>canvas.winfo_width(): 
    #    
    #if x1<0:
    #     canvas.move(circle_item, x+400, y)
    #global direction


        canvas.after(1, animate)
# Call function directly to start the recursion
    animate()
    #
    def move(event):
        global direction, var, x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, new_dir 
        direction = 3
        if event.char=='s' and direction == 3:
            if direction == 1:
                return
            else: 
                new_dir = 1
                var = 3
                for i in range(10):
                    x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = canvas.coords(circle_item)
        #for i in range(food_present):
                    if var == 3:
                        x1 += 1
                        x2 += 0
                        x3 +=0
                        y1 +=0
                        y2= y1
                #x2 += 1
                #x3 += 1

                        y3 += 1
                        canvas.coords(circle_item, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
                        canvas.update()
            if x1 == x3:
                var = 4
                direction = 1
            canvas.update()

    #    if event.char=='s' and direction == 2:
    #        if direction == 1:
    #            return
    #        else: 
    #            new_dir = 1
    #            var = 3
    #            for i in range(10):
    #                x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = canvas.coords(circle_item)
    ##for i in range(food_present):
    #                if var == 3:
    #                    x1 -= 0
    #                    x2 -= 1
    #                    x3 -=1
    #                    y1 -=0
    #                    y2 -=1
    #            #x2 += 1
    #            #x3 += 1
    #            
    #                    y3 -= 1
    #                canvas.coords(circle_item, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    #                canvas.update()
    #            if x1 == x3:
    #                var = 4
    #                direction = 1
    #            canvas.update()

    root.bind("<Key>", move)  

    def x(): 
        i = Tkinter.Canvas(root, width=900, height=900, background='#FFFFFF')
        x = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Use S to move down. Try and eat the food.', command = new_game)
        x.grid(row=0, column =1)

    def grow():
        global x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, var, food_present, foodx1, foody1, foodx2, foody2
        x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = canvas.coords(circle_item)
        if x2>canvas.winfo_width() or x1<0:
            x()
        if y2>canvas.winfo_height() or y3>canvas.winfo_height(): 
            food_present = 0
            x()
        canvas.update()
    grow()




c = Tkinter.Canvas(root, width=900, height=900, background='#FFFFFF')
c.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=1)
text = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Use S to move down. Try and eat the food.', command = new_game)
text.grid(row=0, column =1)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if two objects are overlapping on a Tkinter canvas, you may get their positions by the method of object Canvas `.coords(objectname)`. You use the `.coords` method to check on a drawn object.

Example:

```
circle = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 50, 50)
canvas.move(circle, 5, 0) # moves the circle by 5 pixels to the right
coords = canvas.coords(circle) # Returns an array (5, 0, 55, 0).
```

What you don't do is specify a coordinate to return what object is on it(what I think you are doing).